# How can I increment a String Variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a series of 29 powershell scripts that execute sequentially.  All of the information in each script is the same, but I have a string `$buildID` that needs to change between each version.  Is it possible to do the following:

1. Import the `$buildID` variable from the previous script
2. Increment said variable by 1 (either numerically or alphabetically)

If `$buildID` was an int it would be easy.  I tried to figure out #2 first so I attempted solving it using the below method:

```
$buildID=[int[]][char[]]'TestA'
$i = 0

$buildID[-1]++
[char[]]$buildID -join ""
$i++

echo $buildID
```

This technically works, `$buildID` will show "TestB" afterwards, but whenever I try to use the variable it shows the value is actually "88".  Additionally, since I need more than 26 iterations the alphabet rolls over into special characters (which the system wouldn't accept) and numbers would roll over as well after 9.

Can someone either fix my method or show me an even better one?

Comment: Why not simply use `int` and only pass this value on if the text part is fixed anyway and only the version part changes?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea how this could work using an int which is way more suitable for incrementing:

```
$i = 0
$i++
"Test{0:00#}" -f $i
```

will give you

```
Test001
```

making use of a format string with desired padding of zeros.

Comment: This is good, but then I need to be able to pass "Test001" as a value for $buildID

Comment: @Spawned18 Just do `$buildID = "Test{0:00#}" -f $i` then.